# Can I terminate the scope of a C++ variable without ending a block?

Tags: c++, variables, scope

I would like to do something like the following pattern:

```
T* const pT = findT();
// Do some work
T* const pT2 = new T( *pT );
// Mutate the object pT2 refers to
delete pT;
// At this point, I want the scope of pT to end.
// I do not want the scope of pT2 to end
```

I know I can end scope by ending a block, but it ends up like this:

```
T* pT2 = 0;
{
    T* const pT = findT();
    // Do some work
    pT2 = new T( *pT );
    // Mutate the object pT2 refers to
    delete pT;
}
```

This causes pT2 to lose its const qualifier because I have to assign to it after it's declared.

I want my cake and I'd like to eat it too, I want clear constness **and** proper scoping!

Is there any way to end scope on a variable other than by ending a block? If not, are there any plans to extend the standard to support this?

Comment: So you want the pointer pT2 constant, but not the object to which it refers?

Comment: That is correct, I use const extensively to remove the possibility to error and to reduce the cognitive load of reading my code. When you see me init a const pointer, you don't have to consider the possibility that it's mutated anywhere.

Comment: FYI, oftenly it is the const-ness that causes ppl to take const_cast shortcut and lead to UB

Comment: Can you write a wrapper class for `pT2` which has a one shot assignment and once assigned does not allow any other assignment?

Answer (score 4):

You can use lambdas:

```
T* const pT = []() -> T* {
    T* pT;
    // Do whatever the hell you want with pT
    return pT;
}();
```

Comment: this is very similar with the "scope" solution which TS rejected.

Comment: @YeenFei: Except that it allows him to achieve his objective, that is, to make pT2 const.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to end scope on a variable other than by ending a block?

No.  The scope of a local variable begins when it is declared and ends at the end of the block at which it is declared.

> If not, are there any plans to extend the standard to support this?

This sounds like a really bad idea:  this would add unnecessary complexity to rules concerning scope, name lookup, and object lifetime.

Comment: @DonNeufeld so, how would you do it, syntactically and semantically speaking, in an imaginary extension to the C++ standard?

Comment: Hmm, I can see how changing lifetime rules might make RAII harder to understand / less clear.  That said, this is an annoying problem.

Comment: @Don:  What is the actual benefit of this proposed capability?  The only use cases I can think of are (1) to allow a new variable to be declared with the same name, which for obvious reasons is a bad idea, or (2) to allow an object's destructor to be called early, in which case you can already get similar functionality by adding a "release" function (as is done in the Scope Guard idiom).  A function should not have so many local variables that the current lifetime/scope rules are insufficient to write clear code.

Comment: @wilhelmtell Syntactically I'd probably do something horrible like add a keyword.  My first inclination was 'symbol = void;'.  However I could see that maybe being confusing because you don't want to make it possible to end scope on a variable by accidentally assigning from a function that returns void.

Comment: @James The example I've given is my most common case I've encountered for wanting to do this. I try to make it impossible to accidentally reference pointers outside of their actually valid scope (which as you can see doesn't always line up with their language scope)

Comment: @Don Neufeld, IMHO, we should not waste too much effort in these sub-productive syntax issue. Why not simplify it by remove const-ness and assign null value to the pointer after deletion ? or perhaps extract pT2 construction to another function.

Comment: @YeenFei I see this as highly productive. Detecting entire classes of bugs at compile time is a substantial benefit.

Comment: @Don:  My only advice would be to either (a) simplify your object lifetimes so that this isn't an issue or (b) refactor your code so that the complexity is encapsulated in as small a function as possible so that the "problem" is only in one place.

Answer (score 0):

What you call "block" is another name in C++ for "scope". This *is* how you define a scope in C++.

Another option here is to use a `std::auto_ptr`, which transfers ownership on assignment. The old pointer won't clean up but will effectively be nil.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can however use the following idiom to beautify your example somewhat (okay, that's subjective, but hey):

```
T* p1 = 0;

if (T* const p2 = findT()) {
  p1 = new T( *p2 );
  delete p2;
}
```

Comment: I actually do that a lot, though sometimes my code becomes highly diagonal as a result, which I then have to refactor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) (or [boost::optional](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)) for a fine grained control on object life-time.

Here is an example:

```
std::optional< ClassA > a(std::in_place, 1); // ClassA constructor is called
std::optional< ClassB > b(std::in_place, 2); // ClassB constructor is called
a.reset(); // ClassA destructor is called
b.reset(); // ClassB destructor is called
```

Unfortunately, the name of the variable is still there and its memory is still allocated.

There is also a trick to destroy a string and free its memory (the variable itself is still there):

```
std::string my_str;
std::string{}.swap(my_str); // likely to free the memory
```

It's implementation defined, so it may actually not free the memory, but it is likely to do so.

Comment: The swap trick is not guaranteed to work if you care about the resulting string capacity, though it's more likely than shrink_to_fit.

Comment: It's implementation defined, but usually swap actually swaps the memory buffers, so the old buffer is destroyed along with the temporary string object.

Comment: Usually, but not necessarily.